# Firebase app distribution via Fastlane "the server responded with status 404"

Tags: ios, firebase, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying distribute app using firebase app distribution via fastlane.
When I run firebase_app_distribution, it seems to login into Google successfully but somehow at the end it returns 404.

I login in to Google using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Here is my log.

```
[12:19:16]: Authenticating with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable:'<path here>'
[12:19:16]:  Authenticated successfully.
[12:19:16]: ⌛ Uploading the IPA.
+------------------+---------------------+
|              Lane Context              |
+------------------+---------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios                 |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios                 |
| LANE_NAME        | ios distribute_beta |
+------------------+---------------------+
[12:19:18]: the server responded with status 404
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue. I would suggest you following this instruction

1. Go to your Firebase console
2. Click App Distribution section under the **Release & Monitor** tab
3. Select your project
4. Verify if the **Get Started** button has been pressed

Simple thing but useful

Comment: I missed that 4th point ...

Comment: King! worked like a charm! ;)

Comment: Worked !! This should be marked as a valid answer.

Comment: What is weird is even though I had pressed "Get Started" for my android app and had already released test apps for Android. After I added my iOS app to the firebase project, I needed to press "Get Started" again. This seems like a bug in Firebase.

Comment: Another thing I'd say is I will probably not even use Firebase App Distribution for iOS apps, because apps needs to be rebuilt with an updated provisioning profile for each new test device added.

Comment: Wow, this was so silly that firebase was rejecting the upload because the get started was not clicked. Thanks for your answer, it worked

Comment: I know Stack Overflow doesn't like people piling on with these kinds of comments, but thank you so much ... I was totally lost until I found this answer.